# Why are women's buttons on the opposite side from men's?

Tags: clothing

I was told many years ago that women's shirts had the buttons on the opposite side from men's so that mothers had an easier time buttoning their (male) children's shirts. However, I recently saw a video that claimed it was for women to imply that they had servants to dress them.

Are either of these explanations (or another) supported historically?

Comment: Simple symmetry?

Comment: Fails [preliminary research test](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/1401). Google gives me[Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/03/the-curious-case-of-men-and-womens-buttons/388844/) or [Smithsonian](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/heres-why-mens-and-womens-clothes-button-opposite-sides-1-180957361/)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace that seems to be two news sites* presenting speculation, not so much as a pointer to a primary source. And there is only minimal overlap between them, no definitive answer as to whether there is solid historical evidence. (*: I'm not sure what the relationship, if any, is between Smithsonian.com and the real Smithsonian is, but the speculation and lack of primary sources still stands)

Comment: True - but the preliminary research test means you should account for the obvious common stuff.  Doing history without preliminary research is like building a house without a foundation.  Besides, what they share is the admonition that the truth is unknowable - which would take the question over to the "if you doubt the existing narrative" flaw.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace "doubt[ing] the existing narrative" would require there being a more-or-less unique existing narrative.

Comment: Does it occur to you that it was done to make it easier for men to unbutton women's blouses, since the small motor skill motions would be the same? :p

Comment: I was told in each case it is for ease of access.  For men: sword (on left hip drawn with right hand). For women: breast (for nursing baby on right breast).

Comment: Orthodox Jews button their coats right over left (IOW, as women normally do) for Kabbalistic reasons.